# Can I get ssh public key from url in bitbucket?

Tags: github, bitbucket, public-key

github provide public ssh key by URL like `http://github.com/user.keys`.

Is there a way also in bitbucket to obtain public keys via URL?

Comment: I found this in a quick Google search: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/ssh-keys+Resource

Comment: Thanks, I can get by url `https://bitbucket.org/api/1.0/users/#{user}/ssh-keys`, but only if when I'm logged in. Is there no way without authentication?

Comment: No, I'm afraid not. Public SSH keys are sensitive information and shouldn't be shared with any person who requests the API.

Comment: You mean, github is doing wrong from security aspect?

Comment: @CameronTinker, public keys are by definition *public*. Certainly PGP keys can be (and often are) shared publicly on key servers or on public websites. I would be very surprised if SSH public keys were sensitive from a security perspective.

Comment: @Chris Thanks for the clarification. Without the matching private key from the client, public key authentication won't work. It could just be that Bitbucket requires a login for their API and that's it.

Comment: @CameronTinker, you got it! The private key is definitely sensitive, and should be carefully protected. I think your first comment in this thread is really the correct answer. Why not add it as one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Bitbucket's REST API version 1, you can get the SSH keys of a user with this endpoint:

```
https://bitbucket.org/api/1.0/users/#{user}/ssh-keys
```

Here is a full reference from the API documents:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/ssh-keys+Resource

I'm not sure if they plan to include this in  version 2 of their API, but it should work with other API calls.

You need an account to authenticate your requests. Here is how to use the REST APIs:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Use+the+Bitbucket+REST+APIs

EDIT:
Here's the relevant documentation for v2 of their REST API:
https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/meta/authentication
[https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/users/{username}/ssh-keys](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/users/%7Busername%7D/ssh-keys)

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot get these from users that aren't yourself :(

Comment: @VinhVO, I've added a link to v2 of their API documentation.